# Error incompatible types when initializing type 'enum Zahlen' using type 'struct s_action (*)

Tags: c, gcc, struct, enums

im run into a problem with defining structures in C. I work with GCC.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef enum Zahlen {
    eins =0,
    zwei,
    drei

}tZahlen;

struct s_action{
    tZahlen aZahl;
    void *argument;
    char name[];
};

struct s_testschritt{
    int actioncount;
    struct s_action actions[];
};

struct s_action myactions[20];

struct s_testschritt aTestschritt = {
    .actioncount = 20,
    .actions = &myactions

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the following error at compile time:

```
    [Error] incompatible types when initializing type 'enum Zahlen' using type 'struct s_action (*)[20]'
```

When i omit the enum Zahlen in the struct s_action everything works fine. But i need this enum in my struct s_action.

How can i define and initialize this correct?

Comment: The problem is in the `actions` field. You **CANNOT** assign an array member. Use a pointer or `memcpy`.

Comment: The answer by dbush should get rid of the warnings. But it still leaves the problem that the `s_action` structure also contains a flexible array member, and no storage is being allocated for it. When a structure has a flexible array member, e.g. `char name[]`, you can't declare an array of those structures, e.g. `struct s_action myactions[20]`. That array declaration will not reserve any space for the `name` member.

Comment: @JakubKaszycki: That's not an assignment, but an initialiser. And it works if OP used the correct type.

Answer (score 2):

The field `actions` in `struct s_testschritt` is a flexible array member.  You can't assign an array (or a pointer to an array) to it.

What you want is to declare this member as a pointer.  Then you initialize it with the array `myactions`, which will decay to a pointer to the first element.

```
struct s_testschritt{
    int actioncount;
    struct s_action *actions;
};

struct s_action myactions[20];

struct s_testschritt aTestschritt = {
    .actioncount = 20,
    .actions = myactions

};
```